# PHP Printing with Google Cloud Print

Tags: php, python, google-cloud-print

I am currently adding the ability to a php back-end system to allow it to print directly and I am trying to get things working with Google's Cloud Print. Imagine the app as an online shopping cart and I want it to print picking notes *(completed orders)* without the need for someone to login. The server is remote and the destination has Cloud Ready Printers.

So far I have been successful in getting it to print using the [interfaces](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/appInterfaces.html), as long as I am simply passing HTML, plain text or a URL to a PDF. I am able to set the print to color, marginless and the print quality.

However where I have hit a problem is, the PDF which the system creates are not publicly accessible, hence I can't pass a URL to the file, I need to pass the contents of the file.

I have been trying with no success to modify one of the examples I have found on the web [**HERE**](http://pastie.org/1733781). However I don't know the language so am struggling with it.

Another example in python [**HERE**](https://github.com/simoncadman/CUPS-Cloud-Print/blob/master/printer.py) again I have been trying without success!

I'm using PHP and the Zend framework to work with the interface. Here is one sample I have tried, cut down to where I am trying to prepare the file to send, like I say I'm not really sure on translating from python to php, or if the python script even works, but this is what I came up with:

```
<?php
// Test print a job:
$b64_pathname = PDF_PATH.'ec22c3.pdf'.'.b64';
$fileType = "application/pdf";
// Open the original file and base64 encode it:
$dataHandle = fopen(PDF_PATH.'ec22c3.pdf', "rb");
$dataContent = fread($dataHandle, filesize(PDF_PATH.'ec22ed167763a15e8591a3776f3c65c3.pdf'));
fclose($dataHandle);
$b64data = $fileType.base64_encode($dataContent);
// Store the base64 encoded file:
$ourFileHandle = fopen($b64_pathname, 'w');
fwrite($ourFileHandle, $b64data);
fclose($ourFileHandle);
// Read the contents of the base64 encoded file and delete it:
$fileHandle = fopen($b64_pathname, "rb");
$fileContent = fread($fileHandle, filesize($b64_pathname));
fclose($fileHandle);
unlink($b64_pathname);
// URL encode the file contents:
$file = urlencode($fileContent);
// Add the file and send to the printer:
$client->setParameterPost('content', $file);
$client->setParameterPost('contentType', $fileType);
$client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method in php using cUrl (note, I have object level variables called _auth, _username, _password & _printerId).

First, build a function to post with cUrl:

```
function processRequest($url, $postFields, $referer) {  
    $ret = "";
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "");
    if(!is_null($postFields)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
             $postFields);
        // http_build_query() will properly escape the fields and
        //  build a query string.
    }

    if(strlen($this->_auth) > 0) {
        $headers = array(
        "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=". $this->_auth,
        //"GData-Version: 3.0",
        "X-CloudPrint-Proxy", "yourappname"
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    

    $ret = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch); 

    return $ret;
}
```

Then, a function to authorize against Google:

```
  public function authorize() {
    $url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
    $post = array("accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
    "Email" => $this->_username,
    "Passwd" => $this->_password,
    "service" => "cloudprint",
    "source" => "yourappname");
    $resp = $this->processRequest($url, $post, "");

    preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $resp, $matches);
    $this->_auth = $matches[1];
  }
```

Finally, build a function to submit to the cloud printer:

```
function printDocument($title, $docBytes)
{
    $url = "http://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit?printerid=". $this->_printerId."&output=json";

    $post = array(
        "printerid" => $this->_printerId,
        "capabilities" => "",
        "contentType" => "dataUrl",
        "title" => $title,
        "content" => 'data:application/pdf;base64,'. base64_encode($docBytes)
    );

    $ret = $this->processRequest($url, $post, "");

    echo $ret;
}
```

In use, call authorize() to get the authentication token. Then just read your file (from wherever) into a variable and pass it to printDocument with the title.

Comment: What is in the Auth variable?

Answer (score 1):

In order to send base64 encoded content you need to send another parameter in submit request:
$client->setParameterPost('contentTransferEncoding', 'base64');